# How to query the number of items in a SharePoint list by filter condition

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am using **sending an http request** to sharepoint to calculate the total number of the items in the list, but if I want to query the total number based on specific condition(such as ApproveStatus = Approved), I wrote the link like below, but it still shows the total number of whole items, the condition did not work.

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Reqeust/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RequestList')/?$select=ItemCount&$filter=ApproveStatus%20eq%20%27Approved%27
```

can anyone help me how to do the filter? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The ItemCount property returns the total items in the list. The solution available now sadly involves filtering all the items that match your condition and using the length of the result.

See proposed solution in this question; https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215795/item-count-with-a-filter-condition-using-rest-api-gets-result-in-web-browser-er/215802#215802

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more?

Comment: @zhangguoyuansh, it is not possible to use the ItemCount and filter query string. The ItemCount endpoint always returns the total number of items in the list. What you can do is to filter the number of items from the list and use number of items returned as the count. The post in the link i referenced, explains how to do this.

Comment: thank you so much, I did it, is there limitation about the way? can it work up to 5000 items?

Comment: Yes it should work as long as your filter returns 5000 or less items.